Install a second Fedora on same machine / New disk
Is it possible to install a second Fedora on the same machine without wrecking all installs.
I'm currently having a dual boot Win10/Fedora but this Fedora install is rolling from Fedora 30, so I want to clean it up, being able to grab some old config from the former Fedora install.
I've a new disk to install the new Fedora (sdc 1To), which I want to use as LVM & xfs that's why I need to know if I need a new EFI part:
sdc
sdd
├─sdd1
├─sdd2               vfat        FAT32          xxxx
├─sdd3               ntfs                       xxxx   xxxxxxxx                      41,2G    52% /DATA
├─sdd4               ext4        1.0      root  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx       51G    30% /
├─sdd5               vfat        FAT32    efi   xxxxx                               491,9M     4% /boot/efi
└─sdd6               ext4        1.0      Home  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx      3,5G    94% /home

Can I use the existing EFI partition or I need to create a new one on /dev/sdc and add a chainloader to be able to boot from the /dev/sdd5 which is the former EFI.
# ls /boot/efi/EFI/
BOOT  fedora


I primarily boot Kubuntu, but have installed Fedora to sdb. I prefer to have an ESP - efi system partition as first partition on every drive (even data drives, in case converted later to an install).  I only use gpt partitioning now. Ubuntu used to always install to first drive's ESP, no matter what you told it to do. So when I installed Fedora and chose ESP on sdb, I was pleasantly surprised as that was where it installed. Grub automatically found other installs and let me boot them. If one install not LVM, you need to add lvm drivers to all installs.
